# How to count frequency of string value (from a few ID in the same column)? [R]

Tags: r, string, dataframe, time-series, data-cleaning

I wanted to clean my table but since I'm still new to [R], what I can do are pretty limited. The list is actually pretty long, around 100,000 rows, it would be impossible for me to do it manually ~ Please help me.

Suppose I have a very long list of data in table form. Each of them have a "Publication.Code" and a "Date". The Code is unique while the Date can be duplicated. For each of it, they have a list of "names" under the column "Type".

```
Publication.Code    Date        Type
1   AC00069535742   2009-04-16  E62D 21/15;E60R 7/06;E60R 21/06;E62D 25/14
2   BB000069535652  2008-10-30  F06Q 10/
3   FV000069434701  2007-04-05  E30B 15/;E30B 15/16
4   RG000069534443  2006-07-06  E62D 21/15;E62D 25/14;T60T 7/06;E60R 21/06
5   MV000069333663  2006-02-23  H04N 1/1;G01J 3/51
6   KK000069533634  2006-02-23  H12N 9/1;H12N 15/54;H12P 9/
7   NQ000069534198  2006-02-16  H12N 15/54;H12N 15/7;H12N 1/21;H12N 9/1
```

I wanted to mutate a new column using the **1st 4 alphabets** of each names (That are **E60R, E62D, F06Q, E30B, T60T, H04N, G01J, H12N**) in the column "Type" and count its frequency among the list of names just like below:

```
Publication.Code    Date        E60R E62D F06Q E30B T60T H04N G01J H12N
1   AC00069535742   2009-04-16  2    2    1    0    0    0    0    0
2   BB000069535652  2008-10-30  0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
3   FV000069434701  2007-04-05  0    0    0    2    0    0    0    0
4   RG000069534443  2006-07-06  1    2    0    0    1    0    0    0
5   MV000069333663  2006-02-23  0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0
6   KK000069533634  2006-02-23  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3
7   NQ000069534198  2006-02-16  0    0    0    0    0    0    0    4
```

After that, I would like to sum that up by year, maybe by:

```
Year        E60R E62D F06Q E30B T60T H04N G01J H12N
1   2009    2    2    1    0    0    0    0    0
2   2008    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
3   2007    0    0    0    2    0    0    0    0
4   2006    1    2    0    0    1    1    1    7
```

& also the cumulative sum of each column:

```
Year        E60R E62D F06Q E30B T60T H04N G01J H12N
1   2009    2    2    1    0    0    0    0    0
2   2008    2    2    2    0    0    0    0    0
3   2007    2    2    2    2    0    0    0    0
4   2006    2    4    2    2    1    1    1    7
```

I understand that I can use *dplyr* to mutate the column and count the frequency by Year but I'm not sure how to just extract certain value from the column, really appreciate for any help ~

Comment: Do you have a list of the types (in which case you could use `grep`) or do you have to work them out from the data?

Comment: @RichardTelford Yes I have ~~~

Comment: If you use `dput` on your data.frame, it makes it easier to test solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your Types into vector myTypes, this should work for the first part of your problem

```
require(plyr) 
require(stringr)
df<-read.table(header = TRUE, sep=",", text="
Publication.Code,    Date,        Type
AC00069535742,   2009-04-16,  E62D 21/15;E60R 7/06;E60R 21/06;E62D 25/14
BB000069535652,  2008-10-30,  F06Q 10/")
myTypes <- c("E60R", "E62D", "F06Q", "E30B", "T60T", "H04N", "G01J", "H12N")
res <- adply(df, .margin = 1, .fun = function(x) setNames(str_count(x$Type, pattern = myTypes), myTypes))
res$Type <- NULL
```

This will solve the second part

```
res$Date <-lubridate::ymd(res$Date)
ddply(res, .(year(Date)), function(x)colSums(x[,-(1:2)]))
```

To calculate cumulative values for each column use `cumsum` in `colwise`

```
names(res2)[1] <-"year"
cbind(year = res2$year, colwise(cumsum, myTypes)(res2))
```

Comment: Thanks alot~ Your answers are very helpful. Just one more thing, if now I were to find the cumsum of the value, how should I manipulate the code ?

Comment: cumsum of what? The columns of the second table?

Comment: Yes, cumulative sum of the columns from the 2nd table ~ Thanks.

Comment: While I was testing on my datasets following your code, my R couldn't work properly (it says: R received fatal error) ... not sure it's my datasets problem or what, couldn't find the reasons, was it because there're too many "type" (25)?... If so, do you have any alternative package that can produce the same results? Appreciate for any help, I'm really stuck now ~~~

Comment: Difficult to diagnose. Make sure you are using the latest version of R (3.2.5). Try with only small proportion of the data. If it works, add more.